# Set same navigation bar for UITabBarController child view controllers?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a storyboard that looks like this:

[image: 1]]

```
Structure:
                        UINavigationController -> UIViewController
    UITabBarController |
                        UINavigationController -> UIViewController
```

I would like to apply the same navigation bar for both of the child view controllers of the `UITabBarController`.

I read on multiple pages in the internet that Apple strictly recommends not to embed a `UITabBarController` directly within a `UINavigationController`.

However, I have no idea how to get the same status bar for all of the underlaying controllers (I want all buttons to work the same on all controllers).

As said in the comments, I want both `UINavigationControllers` to look the same, I want them to navigate through the same controllers and I want to add custom buttons that function the same in every `UINavigationController`.

Comment: What do you mean by *"the same navigation bar"*? Do you want it to *look* the same? Or do you want the navigation bars to navigate through the same controllers? Are you trying to add custom buttons to the navigation bar, and you want the same buttons in different navigation controllers?

Comment: @DonMag *"the same navigation bar"* shall mean a nav bar that shares custom bar button items related to the same functions and actions. Both children of the ```UITabBarController``` should have the same buttons with the same action in the navigation bar. I also want to navigate through the same controllers. So I would answer all your three last questions with *"yes"*. Just to make it clear.

Comment: OK - that may be a bit confusing... If each Tab loads the same NavigationController, with the same ViewControllers, what's the difference between the Tabs? Will that be clear to the user?

Comment: They both include a table view that loads different things. The first one loads some contacts whereas the other (second) one loads chats (messages). And it should be clear to the user as the tab bar highlights the selected option and the table view has other content. Basically, there is a `UITabBarController` that has two `UITableViewController` as children (or modified `UIViewControllers` that include a `UITableView`). With the navigation bar (a custom button), the user can get to another view controller.

Comment: Hmmm... so, the user is on Tab-1 (contacts)... selects a contact, and the "contact detail" VC is pushed onto the NavController... the user selects Tab-2... what happens to the NavController? It "pops back" but loads different content? So tapping on the Tab *looks* the same as tapping "Back" but it doesn't really go back? Maybe what you really want is a NavController with bottom ToolBar showing, and add buttons to the toolbar to change the current "mode" of the NavController stack?

Comment: I could not really follow you, I'm sorry... So if the user clicks on the **Tab-1**, there is a `UITableView` with *contacts*, the tabbar and the navbar with some buttons. If the user selects a contact-cell, "chatlog-VC" is pushed, the tabbar disappears and the navbar is modified by "chatlog-VC". If the user is on **Tab-2** (*chats*) and selects a cell, the same "chatlog-VC" is pushed and it looks the same. The difference between the two Tabs is the data of the `UITableView`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165911/discussion-between-donmag-and-t-meyer).

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a good example of what you wat](https://coderwall.com/p/dyqrfa/customize-navigation-bar-appearance-with-swift)

basically you can use

```
UINavigationBar.appearance()
```

To have the same UI for your navigation bar (or other elements) throughout the aplicaiton.

Comment: @AndrejDurnea And how would I implement custom bar button items and actions?

Comment: if you need the UI customisation for the app to be the same, you can use appearance to do it. the functionality you add in each controller based on what you need.